# Laravel views multiple files include blade

Tags: php, laravel

Before creating the admin view file, there was no problem with the include, but after creating the admin file, I encountered such a problem. Can anyone help with this?

```
views
-layouts
  --partials
   --alert.blade.php
-home.blade.php
-login.blade.php

-admin(File)
  --layoutsAdmin
  ---partialsAdmin
  ----master.blade.php
-home.blade.php
-login.blade.php
```

`home.blade.php`

```
@include('layouts.partials.alert')
```

This home page is not the home page in the admin panel.

In short, the problem is that the place I include sees the layout part on the admin side, how can I prevent this?

Error Output:
**View [layoutsAdmin.partialsAdmin.alert] not found. (View: /var/www/resources/views/home.blade.php)**

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, maybe I'm sharing it in case anyone needs it.

I needed to get to a upper directory.

`@include('/.layouts.partials.alert')`